# Unable to return Map from a scala method

Tags: scala

I am trying to return a Map from a scala method as below.

I have two different Maps with some matching keys. I need to find the matching keys between them and pick the values out of them and put them in another Map in the way I wanted. Below is the code I wrote for the aforementioned action.

```
val common      = rdKeys.keySet.intersect(bounds.keySet).toList
val metaColumns = getReadColumns(common, rdKeys, bounds)
def getReadColumns(common:List[String], rdKeys:scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String], bounds:scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]): scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String] = {
  var metaMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]
  common.map {
    c => metaMap += (c -> bounds(c) + "|" + rdKeys(c))
  }
  metaMap
}
```

But the method is giving me a compilations error:

```
Expression of type Seq[(String, String)] => mutable.Map[String, String] doesn't confirm to expected type mutable.Map[String, String]
```

All the method parameters, Maps used inside the method & the return type of the method are of mutable.Map[String, String]. I don't understand what is the mistake I did here.
Could anyone let me know what do I have to do to correct the problem ?

Comment: `.toList` is unneeded. Just `.map()` over the intersection of the keySets and then `.toMap` the result. Don't make a `List` if you don't need a `List`.

Comment: The `rdKeys` and `bounds` parameters don't need to be `mutable`. Use `collection.Map` rather than `scala.collection.mutable.Map`. (The `scala` prefix is not needed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got the error

```
Expression of type Seq[(String, String)] => mutable.Map[String, String] doesn't confirm to expected type mutable.Map[String, String]
```

Because of the statement `scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]` returns a function `Seq[(String, String)] => mutable.Map[String, String]`

You can correct it by `empty` method:

```
      def getReadColumns( common:List[String], 
                        rdKeys:scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String], 
                        bounds:scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]):scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String] = {

      val metaMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map.empty[String, String]
      common.foreach {
        c => metaMap.update(c, bounds(c) + "|" + rdKeys(c)) 
      }
      metaMap
    }
```

P.S. or use `c => metaMap += c -> (bounds(c) + "|" + rdKeys(c))`

Comment: The `+=` is OK, the problem is that `(c -> bounds(c) + "|" + rdKeys(c))` should be `c -> (bounds(c) + "|" + rdKeys(c))` or `(c, bounds(c) + "|" + rdKeys(c))` because `->` is higher precedence than `+`.

Comment: @Tim yep, ```c => metaMap += c -> (bounds(c) + "|" + rdKeys(c))``` works. Ty

Answer (score 3):

`map` preserves the collection type. You can map a `List` to another `List`, and, in the end, cast your `List` directly to a `Map`

```
val common = List("a", "b")
val rdKeys = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 1)
val bounds = Map("a" -> 10, "b" -> 10)
common // this is a list
     .map(c => c -> (bounds(c) + "|" + rdKeys(c))) // this is a list
     .toMap // then cast to it to a Map
```

This code outputs

```
scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(a -> 10|1, b -> 10|1)
```